# Sensor Data pauses upon Screen OFF even when Foreground Service & Partial Wake Lock are used in Android Wear

Tags: android, wear-os, sensors, android-wake-lock, screen-off

With Android Wear 3.2 OS update, the **Accelerometer Sensor Data gets paused when the Screen goes off**.

1. I have used **Foreground Service** and declared its permission in the manifest.

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE"/>

2. I have also used **Partial Wake Lock** and declared its permission in the manifest.

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>

**Until Android Wear OS 3.0**, **Sensor data was coming up continuously in all cases** including Screen Off.

But **after updating Wear OS to 3.2, it broke and it works only when the screen is ON**.
I also observed below logs:
A) When Screen goes OFF:
PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK 'MyApp::Monitoring' DISABLED disabled -> true

B) When Screen goes ON, sensor data comes through:
PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK 'MyApp::Monitoring' DISABLED disabled -> false

Please suggest the solution.

I have checked [Sensor documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_overview#sensors-practices) and as per that, **Foreground Service should be enough to get continuous data**.

Comment: Having the same problem, thank you for clearing that it happens since version 3.2.
I'd suggest adding tags like wear-os, wakelock, power-management

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It allows only 5 tags. 
Could you please share what all things you have tried for continuous sensor data?

Comment: Unfortunately I have nothing more than what you said to add.
I started this issue, if you have something to add or want to make them know you have the same issue, you're welcome:
https://issuetracker.google.com/u/1/issues/228086086

Answer (score 0):

A coworker of mine found something that seems to work, open the 'Wear' app on the smartphone connected to the watch and activate this:
Watch settings > Apps > your app > Allow background activity

Answer (score 0):

WakeLock's not working was a bug, and has been fixed by Google. Here was the issue tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/228086086